# How to exclude the class HttpInvokerServiceExporter from the spring-web jar?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, gradle

I am using gradle 7.6 with spring boot version 2.7.18
It is pulling spring web jar 5.3.13
This jar has veracode scan very high vulnerability.

I would like to know which gradle command to use to exclude this class from the jar which gets assembled.

i tried the below command but it didnt work

jar {
exclude "org/springframework/remoting/httpinvoker/HttpInvokerServiceExporter.class"
}

Comment: The fact that that class is there doesn't make you vulnerable. As long as you aren't using this class the vulnerability doesn't apply.

Comment: But veracode scan is flagging the jar has conditional pass. It doesnt allow the jar to be accepted but when i manually remove the class from the jar and then run the veracode scan on that jar, veracode clears the jar.

Comment: Those scans are dumb. They only check for the presence of offending classes, they don't have context they cannot see if you are actually using that class.

Comment: Maybe but i need a resolution for the same, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Create an exclude rule.

Comment: @M.Deinum I added below code but it did not work

 
configurations {
        classpath {
            exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'
            exclude group: 'org.springframework.remoting', module: 'httpinvoker'
        }
    }

Comment: That is not what I meant with an exclude rule an exclude rule for checking this particular class from the scanning software. As stated it is dumb, it doesn't know context.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly hack together a jar which doesn't contain the vulnerability

```
configurations {
   springWeb { transitive = false }
}
dependencies {
   springWeb 'org.springframework:spring-web:6.1.1'
   implementation tasks.patchedSpringWeb
}
tasks.register('patchedSpringWeb', Jar) {
   from zipTree(configurations.springWeb.singleFile)
   exclude 'org/springframework/remoting/httpinvoker/HttpInvokerServiceExporter.class'
   archiveBaseName = 'spring-web-patched' 
   archiveVersion = '6.1.1'
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An `exclude` on the `jar` task is not helping, because that class is not part of your `jar`.

Spring Boot does not manipulate the `jar` task to build a bad-practice fat jar where all dependencies are repacked into. It adds a separate `bootJar` task that builds a good-practice fat jar, where all dependencies are packed as whole jars in the jar and then loaded with the help of a custom class loader.

To remove the class on the fly, you should use an artifact transform that filters the unwanted class out.

Something like this:

```
val classExcluded = Attribute.of("classExcluded", Boolean::class.javaObjectType)

abstract class ExcludeClass : TransformAction<TransformParameters.None> {
    @get:PathSensitive(NAME_ONLY)
    @get:InputArtifact
    abstract val inputArtifact: Provider<FileSystemLocation>

    override fun transform(outputs: TransformOutputs) {
        val inputFile = inputArtifact.get().asFile
        if (!inputFile.name.startsWith("spring-web-")) {
            outputs.file(inputArtifact)
            return
        }

        JarOutputStream(outputs.file("${inputFile.nameWithoutExtension}-stripped.jar").outputStream().buffered()).use { outJar ->
            ZipFile(inputFile).use { inZip ->
                for (entry in inZip.entries()) {
                    if (entry.name != "org/springframework/remoting/httpinvoker/HttpInvokerServiceExporter.class") {
                        outJar.putNextEntry(ZipEntry(entry))
                        inZip.getInputStream(entry).use { it.copyTo(outJar) }
                        outJar.closeEntry()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    runtimeClasspath {
        attributes.attribute(classExcluded, true)
    }
 }
 
 dependencies {
    attributesSchema {
        attribute(classExcluded)
    }
    artifactTypes.getByName("jar") {
        attributes.attribute(classExcluded, false)
    }
    registerTransform(ExcludeClass::class) {
        from.attribute(classExcluded, false).attribute(ARTIFACT_TYPE_ATTRIBUTE, "jar")
        to.attribute(classExcluded, true).attribute(ARTIFACT_TYPE_ATTRIBUTE, "jar")
    }
}
```